# Integration over product of sinc functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I encountered a question at https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/91
It was proposed $5$ years ago, and still doesn't have any solvers. I am not sure if it's correct or not. Here is the problem

Let us define a sequence $s_i=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_j,...\}, \hspace{2 mm} \forall ~  i \in [0,7]$ where $a_j=\dfrac{1}{\left(2−\dfrac{i}{9}\right)j−1}$

Consider a sequence of integrals $I_n$ corresponding to each $s_i$.
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin(a_jx)}{a_jx} dx$$

Lets start the sequence of integrals for $s_0$. We can check that $I_1=I_2=...=I_7=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
But exception occurs at $n=8$.
$$I_8=\dfrac{467807924713440738696537864469}{935615849440640907310521750000}\pi$$
We have to find the position of the integral for which the pattern breaks for all $s_i$. I am more interested to know why suddenly the pattern breaks.

I am not sure how to approach it. Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: The sequence for $s_0$ is known as Borwein integrals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral

EDIT: For $s_1$, $I_1=I_2=...=I_8=\dfrac{4}{9}\pi$ and
$$I_9=\dfrac{29400029753404336974526538408172065694314014417505148792988051674634690339277367875676479}{66150066945463447511930761432117139064338007206408722021361067837158011699200000000000000}\pi$$